# printing bootstrap modal division

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing, modal-dialog

So I have a modal that looks like this:

## Image1

[image: Image1]

## Image2

[image: Image2]

It has a vertical scroll. What I want is to print this modal without scrollbars and retain its bootstrap css properties. I have less knowledge with printing modals so kindly help me with this. TIA

Comment: The images are brought into the question so all can see the content and the question at the same time. It should help better visualize the question.